# How to get NTWDBLIB.DLL as a 64 bit file

Tags: delphi, dll, 64-bit, sql-server-2000

I am trying to compile and run a really really old application on my Windows 7 box.

It seems to need NTWDBLIB.DLL from SQL Server 2000.  I can get that file, but it is a 32 bit file.  When I try to run RegServ32 on it I get an error message.

Installing SQL Server 2000 Client tools is not allowed on Windows 7.

Is there any way of getting this file?  (Short of making a 64 bit VM and installing on it to get the file.)

Comment: If the program you're trying to run was written in Delphi (and I assume it must have been since I see no other reason for you to include the "delphi" tag on this question), then you don't really want a 64-bit version of that DLL. Delphi is exclusively a 32-bit compiler nowadays; it cannot use 64-bit DLLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just needed to copy the 32 bit version to the SysWOW64 folder rather than the System32 folder.

Kind of lame that the folder with 64 in the name is for the 32 bit stuff and the folder with the 32 in the name is for the 64 bit stuff.

Comment: It also does actually make a sort of sense:  WOW64 stands for "Windows(32-bit) *ON* Win64"... that is, the 64 refers to the *host* operating system.  I can see how it could be bit confusing at first tho.  :)

Comment: To add to Deltics' comment, the reason why `System32` is still called `System32` and not `System64` on 64-bit Windows is, of course, for compatibility reasons. Although all well-behaved applications get the path of system folders programmatically, I bet there would be quite a few problems if this folder changed its name.

Comment: @Andreas @Deltics Yeah it makes sense why they did it when you consider the compatibility issues. But it is funny that you put the 64 bit stuff in the 32 folder and the 32 bit stuff in the 64 folder!

Comment: Sometimes I wish Windows broke some compatibility. Because that way a lot of bad written application would go extinct, and their developers would finally learn to write well behaved applications (or go extinct as well).

Answer (score 0):

Given the error message, it looks there may be issue with SQL Server 2000 executables in Windows 7. I'd suggest you to install a newer client (2005 or 2008 with all the required SP to be run on Windows 7), they are still able to connect to a SQL Server 2000 server.

Comment: Oddly enough I am connecting to a 2008 SQL Server. Alas, there are some kinds of compatibility lost when you move from SQL Server 2000.  Specifically, Development with Delphi's old BDE does not work with the higher version clients.  (I had SQL Server 2008 R2 client tools installed and it would not work.  Once I put the old dll in the right spot, it all started working.)

Comment: I am afraid 2008 no longer installs the old client. As a stopgap, you may consider to use ODBC via the BDE.